# Merge dataframes in pandas with a combination of keys

Tags: python, pandas, dataframe, gis

I have two dataframes that I need to combine together based on a key (an 'incident number'). The key, however, is repeated, as the database they will be ingested by requires a particular format for coordinates. How can join the necessary columns based on a combination of keys?

For example, the two tables look like:

| Incident_Number | Lat/Long | GPSCoordinates |
| --- | --- | --- |
| AB123 | Lat | 32.123 |
| AB123 | Long | 120.123 |
| CD321 | Lat | 31.321 |
| CD321 | Long | 121.321 |

and...

| Incident_Number | Lat/Long | GeoCodeCoordinates |
| --- | --- | --- |
| AB123 | Lat | 35.123 |
| AB123 | Long | 125.123 |
| CD321 | Lat | 36.321 |
| CD321 | Long | 126.321 |

And I need to get to...

| IncidentNumber | Lat/Long | GPSCoordinates | GeoCodeCoordinates |
| --- | --- | --- | --- |
| AB123 | Lat | 32.123 | 35.123 |
| AB123 | Long | 120.123 | 125.123 |
| CD321 | Lat | 31.321 | 36.321 |
| CD321 | Long | 121.321 | 126.321 |

The number of records are not 100% equal in each table so it needs to allow for NaNs. I am essentially trying to add the column 'GeoCodeCoordinates' to the other dataframe on a combination of 'Incident Number' and 'Lat/Long', so it will treat the value 'AB123 + Lat' and 'AB123 + Long' as a single key. Can this be specified within code, or does a new column and a calculation to create that value as a key need to be created?

I imagine I went about this in a bit of a goofy way. The Lat and Long were originally stored in separate fields and I used .melt() to make the data longer. The database that will ultimately take this in requires the longer format for the Lat/Long field.

`GPSColList = list(GPSRecords.columns)`

`GPSColList.remove('Latitude')`

`GPSList.remove('Longitude')`

`GPSMelt = GPSRecords.melt(id_vars=GPSColList, value_vars=['Latitude', 'Longitude'], var_name='Lat/Long', value_name="GPSCoordinates")`

As the two sets of coordinates were in separate fields I created two dataframes with each set of coordinates and melted them separately. My attempt to merge them looks like:

`mergeMelt = pd.merge(GPSMelt, GeoCodeMelt[["GeoCodeCoordinates"]], on=['Incident_Number', 'Lat/Long'])`

Result is KeyError: 'Incident_Number'

Adding samples as requested:

geocodeMelt:

print(geocodeMelt.head(10).to_dict())
{'OID_': {0: 5211, 1: 5212, 2: 5213, 3: 5214, 4: 5215, 5: 5216, 6: 5217, 7: 5218, 8: 5219, 9: 5220}, 'Unit_Level': {0: 'RRU (Riverside
Unit)', 1: 'RRU (Riverside Unit)', 2: 'RRU (Riverside Unit)', 3: 'RRU (Riverside Unit)', 4: 'RRU (Riverside Unit)', 5: 'RRU (Riverside
Unit)', 6: 'RRU (Riverside Unit)', 7: 'RRU (Riverside Unit)', 8: 'RRU (Riverside Unit)', 9: 'RRU (Riverside Unit)'}, 'Agency_FDID': {0: 33090, 1: 33051, 2: 33054, 3: 33054, 4: 33090, 5: 33070, 6: 33030, 7: 33054, 8: 33090, 9: 33052}, 'Incident_Number': {0: '21CARRU0000198', 1: '21CARRU0000564', 2: '21CARRU0000523', 3: '21CARRU0000624', 4: '21CARRU0000436', 5: '21CARRU0000439', 6: '21CARRU0000496', 7: '21CARRU0000422', 8: '21CARRU0000466', 9: '21CARRU0000016'}, 'Exposure': {0: 0, 1: 0, 2: 0, 3: 0, 4: 0, 5: 0, 6: 0, 7: 0, 8: 0, 9: 0}, 'CAD_Incident_Type': {0: '71', 1: '67B01O', 2: '71C01', 3: '69D03', 4: '67', 5: '67', 6: '71', 7: '69D06', 8: '71C01', 9: '82B01'}, 'CALFIRS_Incident_Type': {0: 'Passenger vehicle fire', 1: 'Outside rubbish, trash or waste fire', 2: 'Passenger vehicle fire', 3: 'Building fire', 4: 'Outside rubbish, trash or waste fire', 5: 'Outside rubbish, trash or waste fire', 6: 'Passenger vehicle fire', 7: 'Dumpster or other outside trash receptacle fire', 8: 'Passenger vehicle fire', 9: 'Brush or brush-and-grass mixture fire'}, 'Incident_Date': {0: '1/1/2021 0:00:00', 1: '1/1/2021 0:00:00', 2: '1/1/2021 0:00:00', 3: '1/1/2021 0:00:00', 4: '1/1/2021 0:00:00', 5: '1/1/2021 0:00:00', 6: '1/1/2021 0:00:00', 7: '1/1/2021 0:00:00', 8: '1/1/2021 0:00:00', 9: '1/1/2021 0:00:00'}, 'Report_Date_Time': {0: nan, 1: '1/1/2021 20:34:00', 2: '1/1/2021 19:07:00', 3: '1/1/2021 23:33:00', 4: nan, 5: '1/1/2021 16:56:00', 6: '1/1/2021 18:28:00', 7: '1/1/2021 16:16:00', 8: '1/1/2021 17:40:00', 9: '1/1/2021 0:15:00'}, 'Day': {0: '06 - Friday', 1: '06 - Friday', 2: '06 - Friday', 3: '06 - Friday', 4: '06 - Friday', 5: '06 - Friday', 6: '06 - Friday', 7: '06 - Friday', 8: '06 - Friday', 9: '06 - Friday'}, 'Incident_Name': {0: 'HY 91  W/ SERFAS CLUB DR', 1: 'QUAIL PL  MENI', 2: 'CAR', 3: 'SUNNY', 4: 'MARTINEZ RD  SANJ', 5: 'W METZ RD / ALTURA DR', 6: 'PALM DR / BUENA VISTA AV', 7: 'DELL', 8: 'HY 74  E HEM', 9: 'MADISON ST / AVE 60'}, 'Address': {0: 'HY 91 W Corona CA 92880', 1: '23880 KENNEDY LN Menifee CA 92587', 2: 'THEODORE ST/EUCALYPTUS AV Moreno Valley CA 92555', 3: '24490 SUNNYMEAD Moreno Valley CA 92553', 4: '40300 MARTINEZ San Jacinto CA 92583', 5: '1388 West METZ Perris CA 92570', 6: 'PALM DR/BUENA VISTA AV Desert hot springs CA 92240', 7: '25361 DELPHINIUM Moreno Valley CA 92553', 8: '43763 HY 74 East Hemet CA 92544', 9: 'MADISON ST/AVE 60 La Quinta CA 92253'}, 'Acres_Burned': {0: nan, 1: nan, 2: nan, 3: nan, 4: nan, 5: nan, 6: nan, 7: nan, 8: nan, 9: 0.01}, 'Wildland_Fire_Cause': {0: nan, 1: nan, 2: nan, 3: nan, 4: nan, 5: nan, 6: nan, 7: nan, 8: nan, 9: 'UU - Undetermined'}, 'Latitude_D': {0: nan, 1: nan, 2: nan, 3: nan, 4: nan, 5: nan, 6: nan, 7:
nan, 8: nan, 9: nan}, 'Longitude_D': {0: nan, 1: nan, 2: nan, 3: nan, 4: nan, 5: nan, 6: nan, 7: nan, 8: nan, 9: nan}, 'Member_Making_Report': {0: 'Muhammad Nassar', 1: 'TODD PHILLIPS', 2: 'DAVID COLOMBO', 3: 'GREGORY MOWAT', 4: 'MICHAEL ESPARZA', 5: 'Benjamin Hall', 6: 'TIMOTHY CABRAL', 7: 'JORGE LOMELI', 8: 'JOSHUA BALBOA', 9: 'SETH SHIVELY'}, 'Battalion': {0: 4.0, 1: 13.0, 2: 9.0, 3: 9.0, 4: 5.0, 5: 1.0, 6: 10.0, 7: 9.0, 8: 5.0, 9: 6.0}, 'Incident_Status': {0: 'Submitted', 1: 'Submitted', 2: 'Submitted', 3: 'Submitted', 4: 'Submitted', 5: 'Submitted', 6: 'Submitted', 7: 'Submitted', 8: 'Submitted', 9: 'Submitted'}, 'DDLat': {0: nan, 1: nan, 2: nan, 3: nan, 4: nan, 5: nan, 6: nan, 7: nan, 8: nan, 9: nan}, 'DDLon': {0: nan, 1: nan, 2: nan, 3: nan, 4: nan, 5: nan, 6: nan, 7: nan, 8: nan, 9: nan}, 'DiscrepancyDistanceFeet': {0: 4178.0, 1: 107.0, 2: 2388.0, 3: 233159.0, 4: 102.0, 5: 1768.0, 6: 1094.0, 7: 78.0, 8: 35603721.0, 9: 149143.0}, 'DiscrepancyDistanceMiles': {0: 1.0, 1: 0.0, 2: 0.0, 3: 44.0, 4: 0.0, 5: 0.0, 6: 0.0, 7: 0.0, 8: 6743.0, 9: 28.0}, 'DiscrepancyGreaterThan1000ft': {0: 1.0, 1: 2.0, 2: 1.0, 3: 1.0, 4: 2.0, 5: 1.0, 6: 1.0, 7: 2.0, 8: 1.0, 9: 1.0}, 'LocationLegitimate': {0: nan, 1: 1.0, 2: nan, 3: nan, 4: 1.0, 5: nan, 6: nan, 7: 1.0, 8: nan, 9: nan}, 'LocationErrorCategory': {0: nan, 1: 7.0, 2: nan, 3: nan, 4: 7.0,
5: nan, 6: nan, 7: 7.0, 8: nan, 9: nan}, 'LocationErrorComment': {0: nan, 1: nan, 2: nan, 3: nan, 4: nan, 5: nan, 6: nan, 7: nan, 8: nan, 9: nan}, 'LocationErrorResolution': {0: nan, 1: 6.0, 2: nan, 3: nan, 4: 6.0, 5: nan, 6: nan, 7: 6.0, 8: nan, 9: nan}, 'LocationErrorResolutionComment': {0: nan, 1: nan, 2: nan, 3: nan, 4: nan, 5: nan, 6: nan, 7: nan, 8: nan, 9: nan}, 'CADLatitudeDDM': {0: '33 53.0746416', 1: '33 42.3811205', 2: '33 55.9728055', 3: '33 56.3706594', 4: '33 47.9788195', 5: '33 47.6486387', 6: '33 57.5747994', 7: '33 54.3721212', 8: '33 44.8499992', 9: '33 38.1589793'}, 'CADLongitudeDDM': {0: '-117 38.2368024', 1: '-117 14.5374611', 2: '-117 07.9119009', 3: '-117 14.1319211', 4: '-116 57.4446600', 5: '-117 15.4013420', 6: '-116 30.2784078', 7: '-117 13.2052213', 8: '-116 53.8524596',
9: '-116 15.0473995'}, 'GeocodeSymbology': {0: 2, 1: 2, 2: 2, 3: 2, 4: 2, 5: 2, 6: 2, 7: 2, 8: 2, 9: 2}, 'Lat/Long': {0: 'Latitude', 1: 'Latitude', 2: 'Latitude', 3: 'Latitude', 4: 'Latitude', 5: 'Latitude', 6: 'Latitude', 7: 'Latitude', 8: 'Latitude', 9: 'Latitude'}, 'CAD_Coords': {0: '33 52.924', 1: '33 42.364', 2: '33 56.100', 3: '33 93.991', 4: '33 47.9629', 5: '33 47.390', 6: '33 57.573', 7: '33 54.385', 8: '33 44.859', 9: '33 61.269'}}

and GPSMelt:

print(geocodeMelt.head(10).to_dict())
{'OID_': {0: 1, 1: 2, 2: 3, 3: 4, 4: 5, 5: 6, 6: 7, 7: 8, 8: 9, 9: 10}, 'Unit_Level': {0: 'RRU (Riverside Unit)', 1: 'RRU (Riverside Unit)', 2: 'RRU (Riverside Unit)', 3: 'RRU (Riverside Unit)', 4: 'RRU (Riverside Unit)', 5: 'RRU (Riverside Unit)', 6: 'RRU (Riverside Unit)', 7: 'RRU (Riverside Unit)', 8: 'RRU (Riverside Unit)', 9: 'RRU (Riverside Unit)'}, 'Agency_FDID': {0: 33090, 1: 33054, 2: 33030, 3: 33051, 4: 33054, 5: 33090, 6: 33070, 7: 33054, 8: 33090, 9: 33035}, 'Incident_Number': {0: '21CARRU0000198', 1: '21CARRU0000523', 2: '21CARRU0000496', 3: '21CARRU0000564', 4: '21CARRU0000624', 5: '21CARRU0000436', 6: '21CARRU0000439', 7: '21CARRU0000422', 8: '21CARRU0000466', 9: '21CARRU0000007'}, 'Exposure': {0: 0, 1: 0, 2: 0, 3: 0, 4: 0, 5: 0, 6: 0, 7: 0, 8: 0, 9: 0}, 'CAD_Incident_Type': {0: '71', 1: '71C01', 2: '71', 3: '67B01O', 4: '69D03', 5: '67', 6: '67', 7: '69D06', 8: '71C01', 9: '82C03'}, 'CALFIRS_Incident_Type': {0: 'Passenger vehicle fire', 1: 'Passenger vehicle fire', 2: 'Passenger vehicle fire', 3: 'Outside rubbish, trash or waste fire', 4: 'Building fire', 5: 'Outside rubbish, trash or waste fire', 6: 'Outside rubbish, trash or waste fire', 7: 'Dumpster or other outside trash receptacle fire', 8: 'Passenger vehicle fire', 9: 'Brush or brush-and-grass mixture fire'}, 'Incident_Date': {0: '1/1/2021 0:00:00', 1: '1/1/2021 0:00:00', 2: '1/1/2021 0:00:00', 3: '1/1/2021 0:00:00', 4: '1/1/2021 0:00:00', 5: '1/1/2021 0:00:00', 6: '1/1/2021 0:00:00', 7: '1/1/2021 0:00:00', 8: '1/1/2021 0:00:00', 9: '1/1/2021 0:00:00'}, 'Report_Date_Time': {0: nan, 1: '1/1/2021 19:07:00', 2: '1/1/2021 18:28:00', 3: '1/1/2021 20:34:00', 4: '1/1/2021 23:33:00', 5: nan, 6: '1/1/2021 16:56:00', 7: '1/1/2021 16:16:00', 8: '1/1/2021 17:40:00', 9: '1/1/2021 0:07:00'}, 'Day': {0: '06 - Friday', 1: '06 - Friday', 2: '06 - Friday', 3: '06 - Friday', 4: '06 - Friday', 5: '06 - Friday', 6: '06 - Friday', 7: '06 - Friday', 8: '06 - Friday', 9: '06 - Friday'}, 'Incident_Name': {0: 'HY 91  W/ SERFAS CLUB DR', 1: 'CAR', 2: 'PALM DR / BUENA VISTA AV', 3: 'QUAIL PL  MENI', 4: 'SUNNY', 5: 'MARTINEZ RD  SANJ', 6: 'W METZ RD / ALTURA DR', 7: 'DELL', 8: 'HY 74  E HEM', 9: 'RIVERSIDE DR / JOY ST'}, 'Address': {0: 'HY 91 W Corona CA 92880', 1: 'THEODORE ST/EUCALYPTUS AV Moreno Valley CA 92555', 2: 'PALM DR/BUENA VISTA AV Desert hot springs CA 92240', 3: '23880 KENNEDY LN Menifee CA 92587', 4: '24490 SUNNYMEAD Moreno Valley CA 92553', 5: '40300 MARTINEZ San Jacinto CA 92583', 6: '1388 West METZ Perris CA 92570', 7: '25361 DELPHINIUM Moreno Valley CA 92553', 8: '43763 HY 74 East Hemet CA 92544', 9: 'RIVERSIDE DR/JOY ST Lake Elsinore CA 92530'}, 'Acres_Burned': {0: nan, 1: nan, 2: nan, 3: nan, 4: nan, 5: nan, 6: nan, 7: nan, 8: nan, 9: 1.0}, 'Wildland_Fire_Cause': {0: nan, 1: nan, 2: nan, 3: nan, 4: nan, 5: nan, 6: nan, 7: nan, 8: nan, 9: 'Misuse of Fire by a Minor'}, 'Latitude_D': {0: 33.88206666666667, 1: 33.935, 2: 33.95955, 3: 33.706066666666665, 4: 34.566516666666665, 5: 33.79938166666667, 6: 33.789833333333334, 7: 33.906416666666665, 8: 33.74765, 9: 33.679883333333336}, 'Longitude_D': {0: -117.62385, 1: -117.13931666666667, 2: -116.50103333333333, 3: -117.2422, 4: -117.39321666666666, 5: -116.9573, 6: -117.254, 7: -117.22008333333332, 8: 116.89728333333332, 9: -117.37076666666665}, 'Member_Making_Report': {0: 'Muhammad Nassar', 1: 'DAVID COLOMBO', 2: 'TIMOTHY CABRAL', 3: 'TODD PHILLIPS', 4: 'GREGORY MOWAT', 5: 'MICHAEL ESPARZA', 6: 'Benjamin Hall', 7: 'JORGE LOMELI', 8: 'JOSHUA BALBOA', 9: 'KEVIN MERKH'}, 'Battalion': {0: 4.0, 1: 9.0, 2: 10.0, 3: 13.0, 4: 9.0, 5: 5.0, 6: 1.0, 7: 9.0, 8: 5.0, 9: 2.0}, 'Incident_Status': {0: 'Submitted', 1: 'Submitted', 2: 'Submitted', 3: 'Submitted', 4: 'Submitted', 5: 'Submitted', 6: 'Submitted', 7: 'Submitted', 8: 'Submitted', 9: 'Submitted'}, 'DDLat': {0: '33.88206667N', 1: '33.93500000N', 2: '33.95955000N', 3: '33.70606667N', 4: '34.56651667N', 5: '33.79938167N', 6: '33.78983333N', 7: '33.90641667N', 8: '33.74765000N', 9: '33.67988333N'}, 'DDLon': {0: '117.62385000W', 1: '117.13931667W', 2: '116.50103333W', 3: '117.24220000W', 4: '117.39321667W', 5: '116.95730000W', 6: '117.25400000W', 7: '117.22008333W', 8: '116.89728333E', 9: '117.37076667W'}, 'DiscrepancyDistanceFeet': {0: 4178.0, 1: 2388.0, 2: 1094.0, 3: 107.0, 4: 233159.0, 5: 102.0, 6: 1768.0, 7: 78.0, 8: 35603721.0, 9: 9298.0}, 'DiscrepancyDistanceMiles': {0: 1.0, 1: 0.0, 2: 0.0, 3: 0.0, 4: 44.0, 5: 0.0, 6: 0.0, 7: 0.0, 8: 6743.0, 9: 2.0}, 'DiscrepancyGreaterThan1000ft': {0: 1.0, 1: 1.0, 2: 1.0, 3: 2.0, 4: 1.0, 5: 2.0, 6: 1.0, 7: 2.0, 8: 1.0, 9: 1.0}, 'LocationLegitimate': {0: nan, 1: nan, 2: nan, 3: 1.0, 4: nan, 5: 1.0, 6: nan, 7: 1.0, 8: nan, 9: nan}, 'LocationErrorCategory': {0: nan, 1: nan, 2: nan, 3: 7.0, 4: nan, 5: 7.0, 6: nan, 7: 7.0, 8: nan, 9: nan}, 'LocationErrorComment': {0: nan, 1: nan, 2: nan, 3: nan, 4: nan, 5: nan, 6: nan, 7: nan, 8: nan, 9: nan}, 'LocationErrorResolution': {0: nan, 1: nan, 2: nan, 3: 6.0, 4: nan, 5: 6.0, 6: nan, 7: 6.0, 8: nan, 9: nan}, 'LocationErrorResolutionComment': {0: nan, 1: nan, 2: nan, 3: nan, 4: nan, 5: nan, 6: nan, 7: nan, 8: nan, 9: nan}, 'CADLatitudeDDM': {0: nan, 1: nan, 2: nan, 3: nan, 4: nan, 5: nan, 6: nan, 7: nan, 8: nan, 9: nan}, 'CADLongitudeDDM': {0: nan, 1: nan, 2: nan, 3: nan, 4: nan, 5: nan, 6: nan, 7: nan, 8: nan, 9: nan}, 'GeocodeSymbology': {0: 1, 1: 1, 2: 1, 3: 1, 4: 1, 5: 1, 6: 1, 7: 1, 8: 1, 9: 1}, 'Lat/Long': {0: 'Latitude', 1: 'Latitude', 2: 'Latitude', 3: 'Latitude', 4: 'Latitude', 5: 'Latitude', 6: 'Latitude', 7: 'Latitude', 8: 'Latitude', 9: 'Latitude'}, 'CALFIRS_Coords': {0: '33 52.924', 1: '33 56.100', 2: '33 57.573', 3: '33 42.364', 4: '33 93.991', 5: '33 47.9629', 6: '33 47.390', 7: '33 54.385', 8: '33 44.859', 9: '33 40.793'}}

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Try:

```
cols = ['Incident_Number', 'Lat/Long', 'GeoCodeCoordinates']
mergeMelt = GPSMelt.merge(GeoCodeMelt[cols], on=cols[:-1])
```

The `KeyError: 'Incident_Number'` is raised because you use `GeoCodeMelt[['GeoCodeCoordinates']]` so your columns `Incident_Number` and `Lat/Long` don't exist when you merge.

Comment: Hmm this is helpful, but I must be missing something. I execute this and when I call mergeMelt.head() the columns look right but it brings over 0 rows.  .shape on GeoCodeMelt and GPSMelt show 10,478 and 10,420 respectively.

Comment: Please update your post with a sample of `GPSMelt` and `GeoCodeMelt`. Use `print(GPSMelt.head(10).to_dict())` for example.

Comment: Added the dictionaries. They're sort of monstrosities, but I am assuming it helps to recreate the issue. Thanks.

Comment: Why is there no GeoCodeCoordinates column in GeoCodeMelt?

Comment: The equivalent column is 'CAD_Coords', which is present (CAD being the address that is used to generate the coordinates from). I made my original post attempting to simplify the language rather than using my working acronyms (I don't know if that's bad practice or not). In this case 'CAD_Coords' = GeoCodeCoordinates and 'CALFIRS_Cords' = GPSCoordinates

Comment: For your example, that works perfectly. I have 9 output rows.